# Need help to install AHCI driver on Win XP without reinstall

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sata, ahci

Trying to find solution I came across this [LINK](https://superuser.com/questions/427340/how-to-enable-ahci-in-windows-xp-without-reinstalling) here, but encountered lot of pain and questions which are not described.

I have [Gigabyte MB H61M](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3970#sp) and did not succeed to work it out. Here is my screenshot of device manager :

[image]

First I did not found anywhere which type of southbridge is mine, but one issue is real pain; when pick up the first (highlited on pic) controller (this 2 port) got bluescreen, which is logical for me cause OS is still using this controller for running and AHCI still should be enabled in EFI.

In all instructions I found the updating driver should be without BSOD on both (for me 2 and 4 port) controllers. Any help?

REMARK:
**Please if you don't know/understand, or don't want to help, don't downvote.**

EDIT:
Possible choices of AHCI types are :

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C1&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) ICH7R/DH SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C5&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) ICH7M/MDH SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2929&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) ICH9M-E/M SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A02&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) ICH10D/DO SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A22&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) ICH10R SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B29&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) 5 Series 4 Port SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B2F&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) 5 Series 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B22&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C02&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C03&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) Mobile Express Chipset SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E02&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller"
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E03&CC_0106.DeviceDesc    = "Intel(R) 7 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller"
```

Comment: Unless Gigabyte offers Windows XP AHCI drivers for your hardware what you want will not be possible.

Comment: And you are so smart to give me downvote!? But Gigabyte actually OFFERS drivers which I used.

Comment: Votes are anonymous there is no possible way you can know, without a shadow of a doubt, that I downvoted your question.  You provided us no information about the bluescreen you received.  You have manually extracted the AHCI driver from the installer on the Gigabyte website?

Comment: Votes on questions and answers are anonymous to everyone.

Comment: RE: southbridge. I **think** that the "northbridge" is on the CPU now and H61 Express Chipset is the "southbridge" http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/h61-express-chipset.html

Comment: Thanks. Still have to pick the right driver. Please see 'EDIT'.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem preventing users from updating drivers from IDE to AHCI has been blue screens that could only be cured by undoing the BIOS change. 
The cause of the problem is the driver installed when Win was setup. Since IDE was enabled at install only the IDE storage driver was configured and active.

Therefore you should consider XP reinstall with F6 to add your drivers via floppy if you have it or by manually registry edit.

Comment: Thanks, but since lot of folks did it by updating driver procedure, I would prefer this, easier job.

Comment: Did .inf of your AHCI driver gives more than one option?

Comment: Oh yes, dozen of them. But I stick with those by some Internet sources regarding MB.

Comment: Maybe you got BSoD because of wrong choice..

Comment: With XP, if you use the "second R recovery" option, you can reinstall XP in place and won't need to reinstall your software.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from ide to ahci (sata) after an installed windows xp is painful...
from your mainboard H61 southbridge chipset; its vendor 8086, device 1C02,
so it should be, "Intel(R) Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset SATA AHCI Controller" (install another win 7 and control from there!)

But as soon as you chose that driver and install manually you ll get blue screen :p
(because your os on that hdd will instant crash.)

My solution was: the other device (not the one that gives blue screen,
the other one, probably its empty or connected to dvd drive; their names are 
so similar.)
change its driver by manual, it wont crush.

shutdown computer,
enter bios, make it ahci-sata.
save, do not start os, shut machine.
open computer, connect your hdd to that second sata.

Now; when you start os (windoz xp) it will recognize :D

Answer (score -1):

with your hardware(h61) you must choose the Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset SATA AHCI ControllerDriver from that list above.

greets

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Please don’t give just a one-line (one-sentence) answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I tried, but got the BSOD, as mentioned above.